# Returning a view is redirecting instead of showing it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have this piece of code in my controller:

**SomeController.cs**

```
public PartialViewResult DoSomething()
{
...
List<MyItem> myList= populateList();
return PartialView(myList);
}
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Some", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "resultFromDoSomething",
                LoadingElementId = "waitingRequest"
            }))

<div id="resultFromDoSomething"></div>
```

The code is working OK in Internet Explorer 9 but in Firefox, instead of populating the div called **resultFromDoSomething** it will redirect to another page with the view.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: This might not be it, check the browser console for any error

Comment: What version of FireFox?

Comment: Also, what happens if you remove the data from the partial view, perhaps just leave some plain text to know it loaded? Especially if it has a table in it. Is this the only `form` on the page?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I was in a hurry so I ended up using $.ajax request.